# Struggling to send data to a list in SharePoint via API

Tags: python, sharepoint

I made this code based on the link errors I've got and the small documentation pieces I've found, maybe it's a huge mess. I've successfully done a GET on SharePoint list, but have a lot of troubles by posting items on a list.

Here is the code:

```
# Iterate over each 'categoria_cadastro' in 'result_omie'
for row_data_omie in result_omie.get('categoria_cadastro', []):
    codigo_value = row_data_omie.get('codigo', '')
    descricao_value = row_data_omie.get('descricao', '')
    receita_value = row_data_omie.get('conta_receita', '')
    despesa_value = row_data_omie.get('conta_despesa', '')

    # Create XML for item properties
    item_properties_tree = ET.Element('Fields')
    ET.SubElement(item_properties_tree, 'codigo').text = codigo_value
    ET.SubElement(item_properties_tree, 'descricao').text = descricao_value
    ET.SubElement(item_properties_tree, 'conta_despesa').text = despesa_value
    ET.SubElement(item_properties_tree, 'conta_receita').text = receita_value

    item_properties = ET.tostring(item_properties_tree, encoding='utf-8', method='xml').decode('utf-8')

    print("Generated XML:")
    print(item_properties)

    # Create SOAP request for adding list items
    soap_request_tree = ET.Element('Envelope', xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
    body_element = ET.SubElement(soap_request_tree, 'Body')
    update_list_items_element = ET.SubElement(body_element, 'UpdateListItems', xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/')
    ET.SubElement(update_list_items_element, 'listName').text = list_title_sharepoint

    # Adjust the updates XML structure
    updates_element = ET.SubElement(update_list_items_element, 'updates')
    batch_element = ET.SubElement(updates_element, 'Batch', OnError="Continue", ListVersion="1", ViewName="")
    method_element = ET.SubElement(batch_element, 'Method', ID="1", Cmd="New")

    soap_request = ET.tostring(soap_request_tree, encoding='utf-8', method='xml').decode('utf-8')

    # Print unescaped SOAP Request XML
    print("Unescaped SOAP Request XML:")
    print(html.unescape(soap_request))

    # Make NTLM authenticated request to SharePoint without explicit SOAP version
    response_sharepoint = requests.post(
        f"{sharepoint_url}/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'},
        data=soap_request
    )

    # Check if the SharePoint update was successful
    if response_sharepoint.status_code == 200:
        print(f"SharePoint list item added successfully using app_key: {app_key}")
    else:
        print(f"Error adding SharePoint list item. Status code: {response_sharepoint.status_code}")
        print(response_sharepoint.text)
```

I just want to send the data to the list, and got error 400.